# WHERE clauses with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Currently I have the following line:

```
scope :within_date_range, ->(start_date, end_date) {
  where("(start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)", start_date, end_date, start_date, end_date)
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this using something similar to?

```
scope :within_date_range, ->(start_date, end_date) {
  where((:start_date => start_date..end_date) OR (:end_date => start_date..end_date))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel):

```
t = Post.arel_table
Post.where(t[:start_date].eq(start_date..end_date).or(t[:end_date].eq(start_date..end_date)))
```

Or

```
Post.where('start_date BETWEEN (:start_date) AND (:end_date) OR end_date BETWEEN (:start_date) AND (:end_date)', :start_date => (start_date..end_date), :end_date => (start_date..end_date))
```